# NSThread leak with NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

I just struggling with memory leak introduced by `NSString` in `NSThread`. Please see below.

```
NSThread* myThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(testSomething) object:nil];

[myThread start];

- (void)testSomething
{
   while (1) {
        @autoreleasepool
        {
           NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [NSDate date]];
           // NSLog(@"%@", str);
        }
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:.1];
    }
}
```

This leak provokes by `NSString *str` but how to fix it in ARC?

I have no idea. I've checked with Profiler; but if I use `CFStringRef hello = CFSTR("Hello, world."); CFRelease(hello);` There are no leaks...

Comment: There's no leak in that code. Xcode is wrong.

Comment: I guess you would only get a warning for unused variable "str". But the @autoreleasepool should be sufficient.